# Casting int to double java

Tags: java, casting, integer, double

I am new to java. I read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_type_casting.asp)  that when we're casting from an int to a double type, it happens automatically(as it's widening casting, not narrowing casting). However, when I tried it out by myself with the following code:

```
int a = 3;

int b = 11;

double sum = a/b;  //widening casting happens automatically
```

...but got the answer of 0.0 instead of 0.27. I know that this is wrong since a/b will return type int(0) and then that int will become a double of 0.0. However, I'm not sure how to fix this.

Thank you so much for help!

Comment: This is called int division. Search for that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an `int` value is automatically cast to a `double` value, but it's the **result** of the calculation `a/b` which is executed using the `int` rules (since both participants are `int`).

In other words, first 3 is divided by 11, which is 0, when done in the `int` world. Then that `0` is converted to the double value `0.0`, which is then assigned to `sum`.

You can force the calculation itself to be done using `double` precision by casting either value to `double`, for example like this:

```
double sum = a / (double) b;
```